# Effect size in power analysis when dealing with Poisson based variant caller

Tags: variant-calling

I was trying to estimate the minimum sequencing depth required to confidently detect somatic variant using Poisson distribution based variant caller (such as somatic variant caller or Pisces from illumina).

Power analysis is used which requires significance level (0.05), power / sensitivity (99%) and effect size to estimate sample size (sequencing depth). I am not sure how to calculate the effect size in such context. Can anyone share some insight? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's standard stats, it's a while since I've done this, but it's textbook stuff

Comment: Try running a pilot study to get some preliminary results you can use to estimate the effect size = difference / SD.